# Why is this MySQL statement pulling data from both tables on this JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

```
select * from user_levels
join collectors_users on user_levels.id = collectors_users.user_level
where collectors_users.username = 'testuser'
```

I want it to pull everything from `user_levels` and nothing from `collectors_users`. But it's pulling from both. How do I correct the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `select *` specify what you actually want and use `select user_levels.*` or even better skip the `*` and write out the columns you want  (and consider using aliases to keep it short and tidy): `select ul.col1, ul.col2 ... from userlevels ul join ...`

Comment: Writing columns out is not an option in my specific scenario, but user_levels.* works perfect, thanks!

Comment: @EthanAllen Yeah sometimes it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is getting all the data as the '*' means 'all' columns. You can limit the columns for just one table by specifying the table:

```
select user_levels.* 
from user_levels
  join collectors_users on user_levels.id = collectors_users.user_level
where collectors_users.username = 'testuser'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in running software. Instead, be as specific as you can be about the columns you want in your result set.

```
 SELECT user_levels.*
```

should help a bit.

Comment: +1! Not only does `*` open you to the possibility of someone shoving a blob into each of your previously tiny results, it also means if you rely on column order and that changes in the data you are screwed; and makes it difficult to tell at a glance what data the code actually uses from the table.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest that you use `in` or `exists`, because this is more consistent with the intention of the query:

```
select ul.*
from user_levels ul
where ul.id in (select cu.user_level
                from collectors_users cu
                where cu.username = 'testuser'
               );
```

In addition, this version will not produce duplicate rows if `collectors_users` has multiple matching rows for a singel row in `user_levels`.

Also note the use of table aliases:  these make the query easier to write and to read.